# Switching from fminsearch to lsqcurvefit

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods

Okay, I have made the following code that estimates unknown parameters using ode15s and fminsearch. It then plots the experimental data given and the best fit obtained from the model. The model is made of three .m files (the main model file, the objective function file, and the ODE file):

```
clear all
close all

% Data from problem
tspan = 0:20:360;
data=[0 1
3.05 0.28
2.04 0.18
0.34 0.32
0.63 0.38
0.95 0.46
1.60 0.35
2.27 0.22
1.60 0.20
0.44 0.32
0.75 0.40
1.13 0.39
1.82 0.31
2.20 0.22
0.56 0.22
0.54 0.33
0.86 0.40
1.32 0.37
2.18 0.27];

xdata = data(:,1);

ydata = data(:,2);

% Initial values for state variables
x0=[0 1];

% Parameters 
p0=[1.5   4   5   0.02   2.5];

% Minimization algorithm
psolve = fminsearch(@(p) myobjective(tspan,data,p,x0), p0);

% Call myodefcn and minimize according to fminsearch
f = @(t,x) myodefcn(psolve,t,x);
[ts,xs] = ode15s(f, tspan, x0);

% Plot x vs. x-fit
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(tspan,data(:,1),'-', tspan,xs(:,1),'-')
legend('x','xfit')
title('Biochemical Oscillator Model')
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Protein Concentrates');

% Plot y vs. y-fit
subplot(1,2,2)
plot(tspan,data(:,2),'-.', tspan,xs(:,2),'-.')
legend('y','yfit')
title('Biochemical Oscillator Model')
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Protein Concentrates')



function SSE = myobjective(td,xd, p, x0)
         f = @(t,x) myodefcn(p,t,x); 
         [ts,xs] = ode15s(f, td, x0);
         err = xd - xs;
         SSE = sum(sum(err.^2));



function dx= myodefcn(p, t, x)
    dx=zeros(2,1);
    dx(1) = x(2)-p(1)*x(1)+(p(2)*x(1)^2)/(p(3)+x(1)^2);
    dx(2) = p(4)*(1-p(5)*x(1)*x(2));
```

Now, I want to change the method of minimization by using `lsqcurvefit` instead of `fminsearch`. Based on internet browsing, it seems that I will have to change the main.m and objective.m files, but the ode.m should be fine. The thing is, I'm still not sure what the inputs for `lsqcurvefit` are. What do I need to change for `lsqcurvefit` to work?

It seems `lsqcurvefit` needs four inputs. So, I changed `psolve = fminsearch(@(p) myobjective(tspan,data,p,x0), p0);` from the original main model file and used `psolve = lsqcurvefit(@(p) myobjective(tspan,data,p,x0), p0, tspan, data);` but get the following errors:

```
Error using @(p)myobjective(tspan,data,p,x0)
Too many input arguments.
Error in lsqcurvefit (line 198)
            initVals.F = feval(funfcn_x_xdata{3},xCurrent,XDATA,varargin{:});
Error in untitled8 (line 29)
psolve = lsqcurvefit(@(p) myobjective(tspan,data,p,x0), p0, tspan, data);
Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. LSQCURVEFIT cannot continue.
```

Alright, so evidently lsqcurvefit should not return the sum of square differences that is present in the objective function, since it already implicitly computes it. So, I simply deleted that portion of the code... is that right? I guess not, because I still get errors (in fact, the same errors as above)

Comment: A better question would be also include your attempt at using `lsqcurvefit` (I assume you've read through the documentation and tried the examples?) and describe what is wrong. Do get get any errors? List them in full. Is the result wrong? In what way?

Comment: Okay, added some of my attempts... still none the wiser. Apparently my objective function has too many input arguments for `lsqcurvefit`?